# Populate Spinner in Android from JSON values

Tags: android, spinner

I have this data in `jsonParam.toString();`

```
JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
```

data is : `{"12":"SUBARU","13":"AUDI","14":"BMWA","15":"FORD","16":"HONDA"}`

I want to populate Drop down (Spinner in Android) and want to get the selected value item ID from this data via Drop down in Android ..

Answer (score 7):

First you can get JSON value and stored in Array list.Then assign that array value to spinner.

**Step 1** Get value from JSON Array and stored into array list.

```
List<String> allNames = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray cast = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("jsonarrayname");
for (int i=0; i<cast.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject actor = cast.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = actor.getString("arrayelementname");
    allNames.add(name);
}
```

**step 2** To set the spinner value from Arraylist.

```
Spinner  spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);       

ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                 (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,allNames );

dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource
                 (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, But   I get this Exception "org.json.JSONException: No value for jsonarrayname" while trying to cast   into JSONArray .

as i have shared my data , Server does not provide me with the jsonarrayname.

Do I have to First give this data a name as per the requirement ? if yes , please gide how to do that ? 

Thanks